# Como manejar el error en Typescript y MongoDB: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

estoy queriendo obtener personajes del usuario desde mi MongoDB, pero al momento de enviar el "userId" me salta el error del titulo,

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'MongoClient'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'client' closes the circle
```

Para obtener varios usuarios no tuve ningún problema, esto solo ocurre cuando quiero traer los personajes del usuario. El "userId" se envía y llega correctamente hasta el controlador. correctamente. Utilizo `Typescript`, `express`, `MongoDB Atlas`. Este es mi codigo:

routes:

```
import  express  from "express";
import { getAllCharactersFromUserId } from "../controllers/characters";

export default (router: express.Router) => {
    router.get('/characters', getAllCharactersFromUserId);
}
```

Controller:

```
import express from 'express';
import { getCharacterByUserId } from '../db/personajes';

export const getAllCharactersFromUserId = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    try {
        const { userId } = req.body;

        const characters = getCharacterByUserId(userId);                

        if (!characters) {
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        }

        return res.status(200).json(characters);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
}
```

DB Schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const characterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {type: String},
    characterName: { type: String },
    headId: { id: Number },
    tshirtId: { id: Number },
    pantsId: { id: Number },
    shoesId: { id: Number },
});

export const characterModel = mongoose.model("Character", characterSchema);

export const getCharacterByUserId = (userId: string) => characterModel.find({userId});
```

Asi luce mi collection:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]